# Player:GetMouse() is nil value in roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

so i am trying to make gui pop up when player hovers over it and while doing that follow mouse cursor. i try to get cursor with remoteEvent but sadly it returns nil value.

can anyone tell me what is a problem?

LocalScript (it is located in StarterPlayersScript)

```lua
local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer


local Mouse = Player:GetMouse()

game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").PlayerMouse:FireServer(Mouse)
```

Main Script

```lua
local clickDetector = script.Parent:FindFirstChildOfClass("ClickDetector")
local textGui = game.StarterGui.Door.TextLabel

local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local mouse = nil
game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").PlayerMouse.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, Mouse)
    print(Player, Mouse)
    mouse = Mouse
end)

print(mouse)
 

clickDetector.MouseHoverEnter:Connect(function(player)
    textGui.Visible = true
end)

clickDetector.MouseHoverLeave:Connect(function(player)
    textGui.Visible = false
end)

local opened = script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("Open")
local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")


local debounce =true
clickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if debounce == true then
        debounce = false
        if opened.Value == false then
            opened.Value = true
            tweenService:Create(script.Parent,TweenInfo.new(0.65),{CFrame = script.Parent.Parent.Opened.CFrame}):Play()
        else
            opened.Value = false
            tweenService:Create(script.Parent,TweenInfo.new(0.65),{CFrame = script.Parent.Parent.Closed.CFrame}):Play()
        end

        wait(0.65)
        debounce = true
    end
end)
```